# Why is Falcon 9's fairing so big?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, cost, aerodynamics, fairings

[The Falcon 9 fairing costs millions of dollars.](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/14762/14585) It is [5.2 meters wide](http://www.spacex.com/sites/spacex/files/falcon_9_users_guide_rev_2.0.pdf#page=36) while the [rocket itself is only 3.7 meters wide](http://www.spacex.com/falcon9). There is no aerodynamic reason that the fairing has to be so big, since [Dragon](http://www.spacex.com/dragon) has the same width as the booster. For [small spacecraft like TESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transiting_Exoplanet_Survey_Satellite#mw-content-text), a much shorter (and therefore lighter) fairing with [half the cross-sectional area](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3.7%C3%B75.2)%C2%B2) (for less dynamic pressure) would obviously suffice:
[image: TESS in fairing]

**Why doesn't SpaceX use smaller fairings for smaller payloads?**

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23621/falcon-9-design-why-is-the-cargo-fairing-so-much-wider-than-the-lower-parts

Comment: I suspect this is mostly a business decision. I'd guess that developing fairings to custom suit needs is more expensive than taking a small performance while being able to assembly line/copy paste a bunch of fairings. This saves engineering time, allows focused improvements, and every new fairing could have unexpected sidefects that would need to be tested. Atmospheric forces and effects at supersonic speeds can do strange and hard to simulate.

Comment: Designing and tooling a much smaller and lighter fairing would probably cost more in R&D than the cost of the kerosene it would save to use on this launch.

Comment: @RussellBorogove if Kerosene is in fact the only issue. There is a potential payload delta-v limitation due to drag. I'm not sure if that's the cause of the narrow 40-second launch window ([Why is TESS' launch window open for only 40 seconds per day?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26643/12102)) for this complicated orbit or not, but for a deep space mission with a small payload, a giant oversized fairing could be a limiting factor.

Comment: Maybe that *is* the smaller fairing.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

One of the keys to SpaceX's cost advantage is standardization on common parts. One example is the Merlin engine, which is used on both the first and second stages of the Falcon 9 and Falcon Heavy (though a slightly different vacum optimized version on the second stages).

This is also done for fairings. Fairings are very expensive to make ([around $6M](https://techcrunch.com/2018/02/22/spacex-misses-catching-falcon-9-rocket-fairing-with-a-giant-net-on-a-big-ship/)). Designing the largest possible fairing to work for any possible missions will cost less than designing customized fairings for specific missions. And design time can impact launch cadence.

And building one type of large fairing for each launch probably costs less than building smaller types for various missions, even if smaller fairings require less material. Some reasons are because there are required processes, such as assembly, testing, loading, etc that are safer/more consistent and easier to optimize if they apply to the same size/design of fairing each time.

But even if the build cost is actually lower for smaller fairings, SpaceX intends to recover and re-use fairings. Again recovery benefits from a standardized design/size, not just for the recovery process (which needs space for parachutes/steering jets/etc), but for re-use. Having a small, a medium and a large fairing would mean not re-using each as often and require a higher inventory of each (what happens when you have back to back small fairing launches and not enough time to refurb/test the first fairing?). Re-using a large \$6M fairing twice as often as a small $3M fairing means the large fairing will cost less per launch.

Comment: Good answer why they aren't using a smaller fairing on this launch. Why it's this size largely comes down to EELV. The US Aif Force designed some standards to make their lives simple and they largely permeated the entire launch industry.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolved_Expendable_Launch_Vehicle

Comment: The cost of assembling a fairing is less of an issue than the cost of testing and qualifying a new fairing design.

Comment: @Hobbes I don't buy that. Sure, R&D for _everything_ in a rocket is costly, but a fairing is still much more of a dumb, sturdy shell than the intricacies of a rocket engine with hundreds of individual details that could fail. The reason it's so expensive are the materials, but you'd think the engineers have a pretty good idea of how the material properties scale to different size. Likewise, the ærodynamic properties can be modelled pretty well with CFD simulations, especially if you have lots of reference data from one size already. I reckon it's really the reusability aspect that dominates.

Comment: @leftaroundabout coming from aircraft, I reckon Hobbes is correct.

Comment: @leftaroundabout "a pretty good idea about how the properties scale" is not the same as _actually having tested_ those properties. I have a pretty good idea about the nature of life, the universe, and everything - but i haven't tested any of it.

Comment: @Knetic no you don't. Nobody has a “pretty good idea” about life, biology being much more messy than physics and structural engineering.

Comment: @fectin elaborate? Aircraft manufacturers do build lots of different planes, in particular they usually build quite a few slightly different-sized variants of every model to better cater particularly long-haul, high-capacity or low-cost needs, whilst saving up on the much higher R&D cost of a completely new model or of the real high-value parts such as engines.

Comment: If I may speak for @fectin, I believe the issue is that are talking about making at most a handful of units of each fairing size. Commercial airplane manufacturers typically only design variants of their planes if they expecting to sell in high volume Looking at Boeing's recent models, the fewest units sold was 38 for 767-400ER, but they also have government contract for 38 more for a military tanker built on same frame. Again it's not just the cost of the changes, its the cost of designing, testing and qualifying those changes for customers that makes small production runs so expensive.