# Why is the Delta IV Heavy taller than the Delta IV Medium?

Tags: design, delta-iv-heavy, delta-iv

Looking at below picture, the Delta IV Heavy is clearly much taller than the Medium. Is there any specific reason why?

[image]

https://www.space.com/15078-rocket-launch-delta-4-milestone.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The fairing is bigger (Taller) for larger payloads.

Comment: To elaborate a little, it's a more powerful rocket than the DIVM, capable of carrying larger payloads - so it needs a bigger fairing space to put them in.

Comment: ...though there are exceptions, like the Parker Solar Probe which needed the Ⅳheavy not because of its payload capability but simply to get enough Δv. It actually looked a big hilarious, such a small probe sitting in that giant fairing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe#/media/File:Parker_fairing.jpg

Comment: @leftaroundabout: next question in this series is then probably why the fairing wasn't smaller....

Comment: @PlasmaHH there's https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26725/why-is-falcon-9s-fairing-so-big/26726#26726 about a case where the fairing was similarly oversized for the payload.

Comment: @PlasmaHH in the case of the PSP, I suspect that qualifying Delta IVH to use either the shorter 5m fairing, or the narrower DCSS and 4m fairing would have exceeded the potential cost savings from using them by a large amount.  ULA produces highly reliable rockets, but they have a very expensive cost structure.